# Loading spinner while loading list data

Tags: jquery, html, load, html-lists, loader

I have an accordion in which I am using ul li list which contains a lot of li list. when user clicks on the accordion to see data I want to show a loader while data is fetching from server. once data has been fetched the loader will hide and data will be shown.
Thanks in advance.

```
   Here is codepen: https://codepen.io/uibeast/pen/rXNePa
```

Comment: Can you post the html code. Also the problem is not clear

Comment: you need to an ajax method for this case that when fetch data completed in success method remove or hide spinner @Thameem

Answer (score 0):

**_loader-bar.sass**

.loader-bar

// Before is used for data-text attribute
  &[data-text]:before
    top: calc(50% - 40px)
    color: $loader-bar--text-color

&:after
    content: ''
    position: fixed
    top: 50%
    left: 50%
    width: 200px
    height: 20px
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    background: linear-gradient( -45deg, $loader-bar--color-secondary 25%, $loader-bar--color 25%, $loader-bar--color 50%, $loader-bar--color-secondary 50%, $loader-bar--color-secondary 75%, $loader-bar--color 75%, $loader-bar--color)
    background-size: 20px 20px
    box-shadow: inset 0 10px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2), 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)
    animation: moveBar 1.5s linear infinite reverse

&[data-rounded]
    &:after
      border-radius: 15px

&[data-inverse]
    &:after
      animation-direction: normal

// Animation for bars
@keyframes moveBar
  from
    background-position: 0 0

to
    background-position: 20px 20px

next step in **loader-bar.sass**

@import './config'

@import './general/base'

@import './loaders/loader-bar'